# FXML Loader can't create FXMLCollections

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

I'm trying to create a ComboBox using fxml. and there is this error that says : Instances of javafx.collctions.FXCollections cannot be created by FXMLLoader. And here is the code:

```
<ComboBox fx:id="setBeginWidth" blendMode="DIFFERENCE" layoutX="325.0" layoutY="262.0"prefHeight="21.0" prefWidth="196.0" promptText="Set the Width of the Map">
              <items>
                <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                  <Integer fx:value="4" />
                  <Integer fx:value="5" />
                  <Integer fx:value="6" />
                  <Integer fx:value="7" />
                  <Integer fx:value="8" />
                  <Integer fx:value="9" />
                  <Integer fx:value="10" />
                </FXCollections>
              </items>
  </ComboBox>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you see the error message in the netbeans editor or it's printed out by the program?

Comment: Actually that code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I built a small demo application around your FXML snippet. The first thing that failed me is that the part

layoutY="262.0"prefHeight="21.0"

is missing a space.

When I fixed that, it worked for me after importing

```
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
```

The first is for FXCollections, the second for constructing Integer.

Did you add those imports?

Answer (score 0):

You must declare the namespace for the shorthand fx. Add

```
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
```

to the xml root node.

Answer (score 0):

layoutY="262.0"prefHeight="21.0" 
this line giving error so please give space between "262.0" and prefHeight.
It will be layoutY="262.0" prefHeight="21.0"
Hope it will help you